# For what $n$ is $n^n + 1$ prime?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, contest-math

This problem is related to 2016 HMMT February Algebra Problem 2.

https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2016/feb/alg/solutions.pdf

How does one find a proof for all numbers n that satisfy $n^n + 1$ is prime?

First, all odd numbers don't work; it is well known that $x^{odd} + 1$ has a factor of $x+1$.

Then, all numbers with any odd factors don't work. For a number $n$ that can be factored into $f1$ and odd $f2$, we can group the expression to become $(n^{f1})^{f2} + 1$, which has a factor of $n^{f1} + 1$.

So our number must be a power of $2$. But not all powers of $2$ work. If we have $n = 2^x$, and $x$ can be factored into $f1$ and odd $f2$, then we can group again, as $n^n + 1$ is $(2^x)^n + 1$, which is $2^{x*n} + 1$, which is $(2^{f1*n})^{f2} + 1$.

So our number must be of the form $2^{2^x}$. Testing the first few numbers, 1 (technically not of the form), 2, and 4 all give prime numbers. Is there a way for us to prove that all numbers of this form work? Or, if it is false, to find and prove a set of solutions that satisfy the requirement?

Comment: @Mathphile you're up.

Comment: $2^0=1$ just so you know.

Comment: Yes, that gives $n=2$; $2^{2^0}=2$, not $1$, which also satisfies the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you take $n = 2^{2^x}$ then your number, $n^n+1$, is nothing but the [Fermat number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number) $F_{x+2^x}$. The known Fermat primes are the first $5$ so the primes you found in your sequence are in fact the only known primes that is known to be on this form (the main reason for this is that it's very hard to check primality since the numbers grow so extremely rapidly in size).

For $x=2$ we have $n = 2^{2^2} = 16$ and $16^{16} + 1$ is not a prime as it can be [checked by a computer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+16%5E16+%2B+1+prime%3F) that $274177$ is a factor.

Comment: Thanks. So my guess was incorrect. Any guesses on how to find all $n$?

Comment: @GavinYu What do you mean? I told you all the known primes: $F_0$ through $F_5$. You just need to check what $x$'s gives you one of those and compute the resulting value of $n$'s. Also note that your numbers grows much more rapidly than Fermat numbers so for $x=10$ you would have a number with like $10^{300}$ digits!

Comment: Right, I see. Since we do not know whether the larger Fermat numbers are prime, there is currently no solution to the problem of finding all $n$ satisfying $n^n+1$ being prime. This also explains why the HMMT problem only asked for integers up to 15.

Comment: Yes. So just check $x=0,1$ (plus the case $n=1$) and you will have found all known ones.